# Values for Heston Model Parameters

Tags: calibration, heston

Under the Heston model, the stock price and volatility follow the processes
\begin{align*}
dS & = \mu S dt + \sqrt{V} S dW^1, \\
dV & = \kappa (\theta - V)dt + \sigma \sqrt{V} dW^2, \\
dW^1 dW^2 & = \rho dt.
\end{align*}

The parameters to be calibrated are $\kappa$, $\theta$, $\sigma$, $\rho$, and $V_0$, which appears in the pricing formula.  Below, I've used MATLAB's [`lsqnonlin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html) function to minimize the objective function
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{ask_i - bid_i}(C_i - \hat{C}_i)^2,
$$
where $C_i$ is the $i^{th}$ European call's market price and $\hat{C}_i$ is the corresponding Heston value.  After running this calibration to 170 separate days of prices, I've obtained the following empirical distributions for $\kappa$, $\theta$ and $\sigma$, and was curious if the orders of magnitude seem about right?
[image: kappa][image: sigma][image: theta]

I should mention I placed the following restrictions on the admissible parameter values during calibration, following the paper by [Moodley](http://math.nyu.edu/~atm262/fall06/compmethods/a1/nimalinmoodley.pdf):
$$
\kappa > 0 \\
\theta \in [0, 1] \\
\sigma \in [0, 5] \\
\rho \in [-1, 0] \\
V_0 \in [0, 1]
$$

Comment: I think that you should change your weight parameter. $\frac{1}{ask_i-bid_i}$ is not so good.

Comment: @Farahvartish Do you have any suggestions?  The one used was proposed in http://math.nyu.edu/~atm262/fall06/compmethods/a1/nimalinmoodley.pdf so I went with that.  Actually, is a weight parameter really necessary?

Comment: Another remedy is to use the loss function described in Christoffersen et al. (2009).It uses the reciprocal of the squared Black-Scholes vega as the weight .The parameter estimates from their method are, therefore, based on the loss function $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{t,k}^{N}\frac{(C_{t,k}-C_{t,k}^{\Theta})}{Vega_{t,k}^2}$

Comment: How can you justify calibrating vol of vol to a bunch of vanilla options, which have no vol of vol exposure? It would make a lot more sense to me to calibrate to vol/var swaps.

Comment: @will Good idea, but are those publicly available?

Comment: unlikely. Also, varswaps are vanilla replicable, so i don't think they'll be too helpful.